# Can you copy and paste a Minecraft version folder from a PC to a Mac?

Tags: java, minecraft

Is there a proper way to move a custom Minecraft client from a PC to a Mac (essentially copying and pasting the jar and client.json)? I have a friend that would like to use a custom client but his computer is old and Java simply doesn't work (I don't know how Minecraft is working) with jars. For those that create custom clients, how would we move it from my computer to his? Like I said, any installer won't work as his old computer refuses to run it.

Comment: You should try posting at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Ok. This is kind of a programming related question so it put it here

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use Minecraft from Windows to Mac. All you need to do is copy the folder `%appdata%/.minecraft` from Windows to `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft` on MacOS. Then simply run the minecraft `.jar` file.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft uses a custom Java stored in the Program Files folder, you can just point the PATH to it

Comment: Something java-related works if Minecraft runs. You can find the default Windows path at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher\runtime\jre-x64". Set the path correctly, it seems to be a fully-functional install.

Comment: Ok. Any idea where this is on a Mac?

Comment: Probably in the applications folder. Look for “Minecraft Launcher”